# Xcode segues not working

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

I've connected my segues from the first view controller to the next page but in the simulator the pages don't connect. I just get redirected back to the home app display page on my iPhone. What could be happening?

Comment: Could be any number of things - upload a couple of screenshots of a) your storyboard connections, and your implementation file.

Answer (score 1):

1) Did you give the segue an identifier in the storyboard?  (Select the icon in the middle of the segue line, and the in the attributes inspector panel on the right, look for the "identifier" field and give it a name.

2) In your first view controller, did you call `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` and then pass in the exact same name you assigned to it in the storyboard (send can just be `self`)?

Usually, making sure of the two steps above is enough to get it working.

Comment: The OP didn't say that the segue was called programmately, I think.

Comment: That's true, but the OP said the segue was connected from "the first view controller" which sounds like a manual segue to me, as opposed to a segue from a button or table cell.